# Access Denied to Public S3 Bucket from certain IP addresses

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have tried to make a completely public S3 bucket and access using PHP SDK. This works when I run the access code below from my local machine:

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => "my correct key",
        'secret' => "my correct secret"
        ]
]);

// //publictest2
$bucket = 'mybucketname';
$keyname = 'test_file.txt';

// Upload an object
try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'Body'   => 'Hello',
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ]);

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . PHP_EOL;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

However, as soon as I run it from the test server (an AWS EC2) I get the below error:

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "mybucketname"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://mybucketname/test_file.txt` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess DeniedVTJX7V (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess DeniedVTJX7V4CCKZYG7CRTz+dPA7fsZQnFxTERKxxbP+IpTtMIIsS1uu23fvTruHH3w8KxwGIduCntRBM5u6tIfHdusbCoPw=
```

I have already implemented the following to make the bucket public:

- Turned off all block Public Access settings, both at account and bucket level: [block public access settings at bucket level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMMJb.png)
- Edit object ownership:
  [edit object ownership section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcDFe.png)
- I edited ACL lists as so: [acl settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tCmM.png)
- I even created a bucket policy that should allow anyone to perform any action on the bucket:

```json
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3BukcetPolicyIPAccess",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIfNotFromAllowedVPC",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "mybucketarn",
                "mybucketarn/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is this still not working when run from my EC2 server?

Comment: Do you use the same Access Key and Secret Access Key when running in local and in Ec2 instance?

Comment: You don't need ACLs for any of this. Generally speaking, you should not use ACLs. Also, a bucket policy that gives `s3:*` permission to anyone is almost certainly a very bad idea (unless you were doing it temporarily to test something, in which case it's still a bad idea).

Comment: Run this command on your EC2 instance: ``aws sts get-caller-identity``. This will give you an insight about the AWS principal, on behalf of which AWS CLI is authenticating against AWS API.

Answer (score 1):

This is not to do with the S3 bucket - the hint here is that it works from your local machine, meaning that the S3 bucket isn't to blame but the instance.

It's to do with the role that your EC2 instance is assuming (or not assuming) - create & assign an IAM role that has access to perform `PutObject` on `mybucketname`.

One quick way to test this would be to use a role with the AWS-managed policy [`AmazonS3FullAccess`](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess) attached which provides full access to all S3 buckets.

Your EC2 instance will then have access to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

for HTTP 403 Forbidden error debug these below steps.

1. Missing permissions to s3:PutObject or s3:PutObjectAcl
2. Missing permissions to use an AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS)
   key
3. Explicit deny statement in the bucket policy
4. Bucket access control list (ACL) doesn't allow the AWS account root
   user to write objects

could you please check this command from your ec2 instance

> "aws s3 ls s3://doc-example-bucket/abc/"

If this command is successful, then the credentials or role specified in your application code are causing the "Access Denied" error.
Be sure that the instance profile role has the required read and write permissions for the S3 buckets. For example, the S3 actions in the following IAM policy provides the required read and write access to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the PHP web-server running on your EC2 instance uses AWS PHP SDK and it does **NOT** have an *IAM principal* configured, because there's neither an *instance profile* (AWS role) attached to your EC2, nor a *default profile* (AWS user) configured with `aws configure`.

In other words your AWS API calls are not authenticated, let alone authorized to perform any actions against S3. *Even* if you allow `s3:*` for all Principals in the Bucket policy. Remember: the Bucket policy expects an AWS principal, but your request is not authenticated (AWS API can't figure out who is calling). Hence `AccessDenied`.

There are several solutions to your problem. But all of them can be boiled down to:

- Using IAM policy (recommended)
- Using S3 bucket policy

You can check out [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/) as to which approach to follow, but for your particular problem I would go with IAM policies.

---

**Using S3 bucket policy**

Let me start with the second solution first.

1. Create a bucket. Disable all public access to it.
2. Attach the following S3 bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/ec2-instance-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::yyyyyyyyyyy",
                "arn:aws:s3:::yyyyyyyyyyy/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Create a new IAM role named `ec2-instance-role`. You do **NOT** need any IAM policies attached to it. Leave it blank.
4. Go to your EC2 instance, click `Actions -> Security -> Modify IAM role` and select the role created in step 3.
5. No need to restart the instance. To verify everything works as expected I am using AWS CLI, but it should work with any SDK (e.g. PHP) as well. Execute from your EC2 instance:

```sh
# Make sure the correct role is assumed
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "UserId": "AROAYGJILC6K4AJRGLZTS:i-0aa422c12359ac00e",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/ec2-instance-role/i-0aa422c12359ac00e"
}

# Upload a test file and check the bucket
$ touch test.txt
$ aws s3 cp test.txt s3://yyyyyyyyyyy/test.txt
upload: ./test.txt to s3://yyyyyyyyyyy/test.txt
$ aws s3 ls s3://yyyyyyyyyyy
2021-12-12 11:01:51        0 test.txt
```

**Using IAM policies**

Here, everything stays the same with the exception that you do not need any Bucket policy, but you attach the policy directly to the IAM instance profile (role).

1. Create a bucket. Disable all public access to it. Disable ACL.
2. Create a new IAM role named `ec2-instance-role` with the following policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::yyyyyyyyyyy",
                "arn:aws:s3:::yyyyyyyyyyy/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Go to your EC2 instance, click `Actions -> Security -> Modify IAM role` and select the role created in the previous step.
4. To verify everything works as expected I am using AWS CLI, but it should work with any SDK (e.g. PHP) as well. Execute from your EC2 instance:

```sh
# Make sure the correct role is assumed
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "UserId": "AROAYGJILC6K4AJRGLZTS:i-0aa422c12359ac00e",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/ec2-instance-role/i-0aa422c12359ac00e"
}

# Upload a test file and check the bucket
$ touch test.txt
$ aws s3 cp test.txt s3://yyyyyyyyyyy/test.txt
upload: ./test.txt to s3://yyyyyyyyyyy/test.txt
$ aws s3 ls s3://yyyyyyyyyyy
2021-12-12 11:01:51        0 test.txt
```

---

Last but not least for both approaches: do not use ACLs (configure your bucket with `ACLs disabled`) since ACLs exist for backward compatibility in favor of Bucket policies, see details in the same [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/):

> As a general rule, AWS recommends using S3 bucket policies or IAM
> policies for access control. S3 ACLs is a legacy access control
> mechanism that predates IAM.

---

In the above snippets:

- `xxxxxxxxxxx` is your AWS account number, e.g. `561262107623`
- `yyyyyyyyyyy` is your bucket name, e.g. `mybucket`